# Querying across multiple SQLAlchemy many-to-many relationships

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy to model the following concept:

- A User can be a `member_of` a Group
- A Group can have multiple users as `members` and can provide `access_to` multiple `Nodes`.
- A node can be `accessed_by` multiple `Groups`

I'm using the association table pattern to create many to many relationships for User -> Group and Node -> Group.

The code is below (I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy which is why I have db.Model, etc)

**How can I query for all the Nodes that can be accessed by all of the Groups that a user is a member of?**

Here's the object model

```
group_access = Table('access', db.metadata,
                     Column('group_id', Integer, ForeignKey('groups.group_id')),
                     Column('nid', BigInteger, ForeignKey('nodes.nid')),
                     )

group_membership = Table('membership', db.metadata,
                         Column('group_id', Integer, ForeignKey('groups.group_id')),
                         Column('uid', Integer, ForeignKey('users.id')),
                         )

edges = Table('edges', db.metadata,
              Column('src_id', BigInteger, ForeignKey('nodes.nid'), primary_key=True),
              Column('dest', BigInteger, ForeignKey('nodes.nid'), primary_key=True),
              )


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    member_of = relationship("Group", secondary=group_membership, back_populates='members')

    def __init__(self, email):
        self.email = email


class Node(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'nodes'

    nid = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String)
    parents = relationship("Node",
                           secondary=edges,
                           primaryjoin="Node.nid==edges.c.src_id",
                           secondaryjoin="Node.nid==edges.c.dest",
                           backref="children")
    accessed_by = relationship("Group", secondary=group_access, back_populates='access_to')

    def __init__(self, owner=None, type=None):
        self.type = type
        # self.owner = owner

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<{} nid:{} >".format(self.type, self.nid)


class Group(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'groups'

    group_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String)
    members = relationship("User", secondary=group_membership, back_populates="member_of")
    access_to = relationship("Node", secondary=group_access, back_populates="accessed_by")

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.type = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.type
```

Comment: How would you like to query the nodes? As a separate query, or would you like to eagerload them when fetching a user?

Comment: Let's say as a separate query and let's assume that the Nodes themselves that a given user can access might not have a parent-child relationship. So the data will be a tree where a user can access distinct nodes within it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A query to fetch nodes related to a given user could be formed using joins:

```
db.session.query(Node).\
    join(Node.accessed_by).\
    join(Group.members).\
    filter(User.id == u.id).\
    all()
```

Due to how SQLAlchemy handles model entities duplicate rows aren't a problem. You could also employ EXISTS, which would not produce duplicates:

```
db.session.query(Node).\
    filter(Node.accessed_by.any(
        Group.members.any(User.id == u.id))).\
    all()
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! i like both much better than what I came up with. Each does what I was stuck on - traversing the relationships.

Comment: There's an even shorter way to write such "traversing", but it might seem confusing at first. In a single entity query `join()` also accepts strings as names of relationship attributes to join, so the 2 separate joins could be written as `join("accessed_by", "members")`.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with something that works, but am not sure if this is the best way to do it as I'm not a SQLAlchemy or database guru. Also, the query doesn't use the relationships directly and I thought there might be a better way to do it.

```
def find_nodes_for_user(u):
    users_groups = db.session.query(group_membership.c.group_id) \
                             .filter(group_membership.c.uid == u.id) \
                             .subquery()
    node_id = db.session.query(group_access.c.nid) \
                        .filter(group_access.c.group_id.in_(users_groups)) \
                        .subquery()
    return db.session.query(Node).filter(Node.nid.in_(node_id)).all()
```

This produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT nodes.nid AS nodes_nid, nodes.type AS nodes_type 
FROM nodes 
WHERE nodes.nid IN (SELECT access.nid 
FROM access 
WHERE access.group_id IN (SELECT membership.group_id 
FROM membership 
WHERE membership.uid = %(uid_1)s))
```

Is this the best way to do it?

Comment: Perfectly fine, though you could express the same with joins less verbosely, or use EXISTS.

Comment: Thanks! Could you post an example of what you're thinking?